# Problems with Java XML RemoveChild

Tags: java, xml

I have the following code:

```
try {
    Builder builder = new Builder();
    Document doc = builder.build(Config.PATH +"incasation.xml");

    Element root = doc.getRootElement();    
    Elements childs = root.getChildElements("locations");

    int nodeToDelete = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < childs.size(); i++)
    {
        Element child = childs.get(i);
        System.out.print(child.getFirstChildElement("name").getValue());
        System.out.print(" - ");
        System.out.print(getLocationName().getText());
        System.out.print(" - ");
        System.out.println(child.getFirstChildElement("name").getValue().equals(getLocationName().getText()));

        if(child.getFirstChildElement("name").getValue().equals(getLocationName().getText()))
        {
            nodeToDelete = i;
        }
    }

    root.removeChild(nodeToDelete);
    Simplexml sx = new Simplexml();
    sx.save(root, Config.PATH +"incasation.xml");
}
catch(Exception e) {}
```

And my question is:

Why is `removeChild(i)` not working?

EDIT:
After a week i found the solution :)

```
root.removeChild(nodeToDelete);         
Element root2 = (Element) root.copy();

Simplexml sx = new Simplexml();
sx.save(root2, Config.PATH +"incasation.xml");
```

[Java appending XML docs to existing docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883987/java-appending-xml-docs-to-existing-docs)

Comment: please explain `is not working`... Also, what is the value of `nodeToDelete` before passing it to removeChild ?

Comment: I can't see any method with signature removeChild(int) in `org.w3c.dom.Element`, what is the class of your Element object ?

Comment: class is XOM, and nodeToDelete int i to n, And `its not working` i mean that is not removed

Answer (score 0):

Compile time error? `org.w3c.dom.Element#removeChild` expects a `Node` object rather then an integer value. Or do you use a different class named `Element`?