# remove empty tag pairs from HTML fragment

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have a user-submitted string that contains HTML content such as

```
"<p></p><div></div><p>Hello<br/>world</p><p></p>"
```

I would like to transform this string such that empty tag pairs are removed (but empty tags like `<br/>` are retained). For example, the result of this transformation should convert the string above to

```
"<p>Hello<br/>world</p>"
```

**I'd like to use JSoup to do this, as I already have this on my classpath, and it would be easiest for me to perform this transformation on the server-side.**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is an example that does just that (using JSoup):

```java
String html = "<p></p><div></div><p>Hello<br/>world</p><p></p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for (Element element : doc.select("*")) {
    if (!element.hasText() && element.isBlock()) {
        element.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println(doc.body().html())
```

The output of the code above is what you are looking for:

```
<p>Hello<br />world</p>
```

Comment: I tested it out and the code above prints `<p>Hello<br />world</p>`

Comment: I noticed that this code remove the empty img inside a div ex: <div><img ...></div> so I checked for empty size also: && element.childNodes().size() == 0 , does my update correct ?

Comment: I think it would be more correct if the `if` statement is like this: `if ((!element.hasText() && element.isBlock()) || (!element.hasText() && element.childNodes().isEmpty())) element.remove()` as it also remove non-block elements which are empty, such as `<span></span>`

Comment: how do I remove any empty tag ??

Comment: @Mark: The main problem with your approach are the self-closing Tags. You will filter as well `<br>` which should be kept!

Answer (score 8):

Not really familiar with jsoup, but you could do this with a simple regex replace:

```
String html = "<p></p><div></div><p>Hello<br/>world</p><p></p>";
html = html.replaceAll("<([^>]*)></\\1>", "");
```

Although with a full parser you could probably just drop empty content during processing, depending on what you're eventually going to do with it.

Comment: replaceAll("<[a-zA-Z0-9]*></[a-zA-Z0-9]*>", ""); may look better than allowing anything other than >

Comment: But what about <i>Italic<b></i>Bold</b> ?  It's bad use, but still legitimate.  I thing you need to be able to rematch exactly what was used in the first set of angle brackets.

Comment: @PragalathanM, I considered that, but tags also permit hyphens, underscores, etc. Once you start adding all those characters, the statement starts looking ugly (and you might miss some).

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: <i>Italic<b></i>Bold</b> is not legal in HTML.

Comment: This solution will only work for `<p></p>`, not for `<p/>` or `<p> </p>` which are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup will make correct XML from user-input HTML. Use XML parser to find and remove all empty tags. I think it's a better idea than regexp. Look here: [Java Remove empty XML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687203/java-remove-empty-xml-tags)
You can also use JSoup to find empty tags for you. Look here : http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax
and use Node.remove() method.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, you can do it like

```
var tags = "<p></p><div></div><p>Hello<br/>world</p><p></p>";

$("<div id='mydiv'>"+tags+"</div>").appendTo($('body'));
$('#mydiv').children().each(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    if(elem.html() === "") elem.remove();
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LqCx5/2/

Comment: updated the answer.. pls check, its working fine i have tested in my machine.

Comment: This will remove all empty tags, including <br/>

Comment: nope dude.. You should revert the downvote... its not removing <br/>.. pls check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LqCx5/3/ ... check the body output, hello and world are in different line.

Answer (score -2):

dont know the Jsoup,below code also works with simple javascript regex.
try the below code.

```
function removeall(){
var tagarray=new Array("<p>","<div>");
source="<p></p><div></div><p>Hello<br/>world</p><p></p>";
for ( var int = 0; int < tagarray.length; int++) {
tag2=tagarray[int].replace("<","</");
var tagpair=new RegExp(tagarray[int]+tag2,"g");
source=source.replace(tagpair,"");
    }
alert(source);
```

}

Comment: This is Java question, so JavaScript code is not a valid answer.