# Dynamic XML Element Names in the same Structure

Tags: java, xml

Suppose I had the following class for modelling an XML output:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "dataObj")
public class DataObj implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String value;

    public DataObj(){}
    public DataObj(String v){
        this.value = v;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setValue(String v){
        this.value = v;
    }
}
```

This would produce the following XML File:

```
<dataObj>
    <value>
        Some Value
    </value>
</dataObj>
```

This is grand, however, my API has many different XML outputs, all following the above XML Structure but have different element names.

For example:

```
<person>
    <name>
        John Doe
    </name>
</person>
```

and

```
<car>
    <color>
        Sky Blue
    </color>
</car>
```

At the moment I have 10 different classes using the same XML structure.

Is there a way of using one class to define the XML structure, but dynamically changing the element names?

Answer (score 0):

Define an XSD containing all the XML tags you require like below:

```
<xsd:complexType name="YourClass">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="person">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="name" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="car">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="color" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    ............. and so on
</xsd:complexType>
```

Then generate the canonical class (POJO) from this XSD with which you will generate the XML.
After generating the XML you can remove all the blank tags using a XSLT (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687203/java-remove-empty-xml-tags)).