# How to replace xml empty tags using regex

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have a lot of empty xml tags which needs to be removed from string.

```
 String dealData = dealDataWriter.toString();
 someData = someData.replaceAll("<somerandomField1/>", "");
 someData = someData.replaceAll("<somerandomField2/>", "");
 someData = someData.replaceAll("<somerandomField3/>", "");
 someData = someData.replaceAll("<somerandomField4/>", "");
```

This uses a lot of string operations which is not efficient, what can be better ways to avoid these operations.

Comment: Your string is actually a xml content ? You should use a java xml parser and delete your empty tags with it; it will be more efficiant.

Comment: Also you should specify what exactly you want to remove - are `<somerandomField1 />`, `<somerandomField1></somerandomField1>`, `<somerandomField1 xsi:nil="true"/>`, `<somerandomField1 xsi:nil="true"></somerandomField1>` empty tags? They are all empty elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest to use Regex when operating on HTML/XML... but for a simple case like yours maybe it is ok to use a rule like this one:

```
someData.replaceAll("<\\w+?\\/>", "");
```

Test: [link](https://regex101.com/r/ZEbnyX/1)

If you want to consider also the optional spaces before and after the tag names:

```
someData.replaceAll("<\\s*\\w+?\\s*\\/>", "");
```

Test: [link](https://regex101.com/r/ZEbnyX/2)

Comment: I would account for a probable space after the nodename with `\s?` or even `\s*`

Comment: What's the purpose of  \\ preceding `/`?

Comment: You're totally right, thanks (OP: do you see how inadeguate can regex be for xml?)

Comment: And there's tons of characters except \w that might appear. The hyphen is just one that's popular.

Comment: @laune you have to put a backslash to consider a character literally in Regex. Since we're in Java, you have to put an extra backslash for the same reason

Comment: @laune you're right, it is very hard to cover every possible case. OP should tell us more about his particular case, maybe he doesn't need to have a 100% general solution

Comment: @Oneiros I guess you tried to escape the forward slash by adding the two backward slashes. Actually no need to escape forward slash.

Comment: @NaveedS I tried to not escape the forward slash in regex101.com and it gave me an error. It doesn't harm to be extra precise anyway

Comment: @Oneiros It is because it was not tried as a java regex. You tried with forward slash as delimiter for regex. No need to escape it in java.

Comment: @NaveedS Ok, thanks for pointing it out. But I personally like to always escape literal characters, just to be sure. Java doesn't care, maybe another language does.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, You can remove all the tag which does not have any space in it.

> someData.replaceAll("<\w+/>","");

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using regex or string matching, you can use an xml parser to find empty tags and remove them.

See the answers given over here:  [Java Remove empty XML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687203/8684601)

Answer (score 0):

If you like to remove `<tagA></tagA>` and also `<tagB/>` you can use following regex. Please note that \1 is used to back reference matching group.

```
// identifies empty tag i.e <tag1></tag> or <tag/>
// it also supports the possibilities of white spaces around or within the tag. however tags with whitespace as value will not match.
private static final String EMPTY_VALUED_TAG_REGEX = "\\s*<\\s*(\\w+)\\s*></\\s*\\1\\s*>|\\s*<\\s*\\w+\\s*/\\s*>";
```

Run the code on [ideone](https://ideone.com/R9S7jU)