# How to create XML file?

Tags: java, xml

I have some data which my program discovers after observing a few things about files.

For instance, i know file name, time file was last changed, whether file is binary or ascii text, file content (assuming it is properties) and some other stuff.

i would like to store this data in XML format.

How would you go about doing it?

Please provide example.

Comment: <fileinfo><file><name>...</name><timechanged>...</timechanged></file><file>...</file></fileinfo>  Just use System.out.println

Comment: right. aren't there some XML libraries i can reuse to create elements?

Comment: Very similar content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831865/what-java-xml-library-do-you-recommend-to-replace-dom4j

Comment: Maybe that's how James Black creates XML. You did ask "How would **you** go about doing it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something quick and relatively painless, use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), which lets you serialise Java Objects to and from XML. The [tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) contains some quick examples.

Comment: This is beyond awesome. Thank you!

Comment: There are many XML binding solutions. JAXB (JSR-222) is the industry standard.  An implementation is included in Java SE 6.  Do a quick stackoverflow search for technology comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Use [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX); it's *so much easier* than SAX or DOM to write an XML file (DOM is probably the easiest to *read* an XML file but requires you to have the whole thing in memory), and is built into Java SE 6.

A good demo is found [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/09/17/stax.html?page=2) on p.2:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("data.xml");
XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(out);
writer.writeStartDocument("ISO-8859-1", "1.0");
writer.writeStartElement("greeting");
writer.writeAttribute("id", "g1");
writer.writeCharacters("Hello StAX");
writer.writeEndDocument();
writer.flush();
writer.close();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard are the W3C libraries.

```
final Document docToSave = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
final Element fileInfo = docToSave.createElement("fileInfo");
docToSave.appendChild(fileInfo);
final Element fileName = docToSave.createElement("fileName");
fileName.setNodeValue("filename.bin");
fileInfo.appendChild(fileName);

return docToSave;
```

XML is almost never the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to do that SAX or DOM, review this link: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1044810.html
I think is that you want