# Getting the content of a table from a Word Template in XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, ms-word

I am trying to create a MS Word 2003 (.doc) file from an XML template. I am trying to replace my placeholders in the XML file with the content i want to insert in the word document.
I have used the following code to replace the content:

```
Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put("NAME","XYZ");
ht.put("ROLL","123");       
while ((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
 if(thisLine.contains("##"))
 {
  for (java.util.Enumeration e = ht.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
  String name = (String) e.nextElement();
  String value = ht.get(name).toString();
  thisLine = thisLine.replaceAll("##" + name.toUpperCase() + "##", value);
 }
}
```

`##id##` is my place holder in the XML file.

It runs properly when the placeholders are in a paragraph, but the problem with this code is that it does not replace the placeholders which are within a `table` in the XML word template.

So my question is how can I read the content of a table of an XML template using a simple java code so that I can replace the placeholders.

Comment: can you put your xml code? And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884051/how-to-update-xml-file-from-another-xml-file-dynamically/9884503#9884503

Comment: @Riddhish.Chaudhari: its not just a simple XML file, its actually a word file converted into XML.

Comment: if you have converted into xml, than it's have opening/closing tag so you can read it by DOM parser or using NodeList.

Comment: okay.. here it is `<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>`
But the DOM parser will just allow me to view the contents in the file. Can I replace the contents using the code above??

Comment: from getAttribute() you get tag attribute name,from getTagName() you get tag name ,and from getTextContent() you get the content inside tag. yes you replace the contents using above code.

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821943/replace-data-in-xml-file-in-java/9870940#9870940

Comment: im working on it. Thanks. :) But is there an other method instead of using the DOM parser?? Just curious.